# How to overcome new line creation when using Javascript in Zapier

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

First time posting on StackOverflow so go easy on me. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a zap that gets data from a Google sheet and adds it to an array in a Javascript document. I used Zapier code to create the array items. I used two ways to achieve that, and both gave me the same issue.

**1st way**: I pushed zap data into a new array to change the way it's written using this code:

```js
/* inputData is the array that zapier puts your data in when using zap code
it looks like this: inputData = {com1: 'company name 1', com2: 'company name 2'}*/

var newArray = [];
var size = Object.keys(inputData).length;
console.log(size);
for (var i = 0; i < size ; i++ ){
    
    if (inputData['com' + i] != null && inputData['com' + i] != ''){
        newArray.push('\"' + inputData['com' + i] + '\" ');
    }else{
    }
}
var output = {company: newArray};

/* the Idea here is to make the new array look like this output = ["company name 1", "company name 2", etc]
```

**2nd way**: was to simply take the data and output it and use it in the final step of the zap.

BOTH worked (syntax wise) so in the final product the syntax is correct but some new line issue breaks the whole thing.

The outcome of the array:

[The outcome of the zap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz5Fs.png)

That's how it looks in the final product, and IF I delete the new lines, then it works normally. I don't know how to get away from those new lines or how to go around the issue.

```js
company: {com0: 'company name 1
',com1: 'company name 2  //this is the issue, 
',com2: 'company name 4
',com3: 'company name 4
',com4: 'company name 5
'},
```

Comment: Hi newcomer!
Could you be more specific on the details of your Zap?
Please give us
- sample data placed in your google sheet
- the specific google sheet Zap that you are using

Comment: Hi, the sample data is written in the first snippet as a comment, 
specific details of my zap

Comment: I have a google sheet with 5 company names, I want to make them an array and put that array string  inside a google drive create document (I create an html file like that) its fairy straight forward

Comment: Is this using the “New Worksheet/Spreadsheet” Trigger or the “New Spreadsheet Row” Trigger?

Comment: New or updated spreadsheet row trigger

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate the issue. I've validated the JS code itself, but the code has no issues when it comes to forming the final array, so the issue seems to be on the Zapier side. I've tried adding a new step to Zapier to create a new google drive document with the following settings: "Create file from text trigger", Filename: "zapier.html", File content: (output array obtained from previous step). This though creates the array without any line breaks. Are your Zap settings similar to mine?

Comment: Or the initial data in Google Sheets may actually contain line breaks, if this data is not inputted manually

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I am doing the same thing as you, create a GD file from text (html file)but I still get the line break, I will test with different 'manual' input and see if that works

Comment: I've tested the manual data and it worked so somehow googlesheet cells are adding a line break. if you have any idea how to overcome that that would be great, if not then we delete this who question?

Comment: Thanks for testing the manual input.
Seeing that the manual input outputs your desired format, could you share with us what automatic input you used to cause the line breaks? Were you using Google Forms as the input? 
I just want to be able to replicate it on my end as well.

Comment: I used data from a google sheet which in turn got its data from a JotForm through a zap. So it went like this JotForms > zap > google sheet > zap (line breaks happened here)

Comment: I went ahead to try the zap that you stated, but could not replicate the issue. Any indication on the Form Elements used for the JotForms input, the data that you entered and the browser you used would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer, It seems like the data coming from google Sheet adds an invisible new line. and to fix the issue I used string.trim() which made it work.

```js
var newArray = [];
var size = Object.keys(inputData).length;
console.log(size);
for (var i = 0; i < size ; i++ ){
    
    if (inputData['com' + i] != null && inputData['com' + i] != ''){
        var line = inputData[i];
        newArray.push('\"' + line.trim() + '\" ');
    }else{
    }
}
var output = {company: newArray};
```

To be clear, this helps anyone using zapier to pull data from GOOGLE SHEET to a Javascript document.